# FindFirstFile and "." / ".." record attributes

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

What object is the meta-data of the dot/double-dot file records as returned by FindFirstFile on a directory referring to?

In practice they seem to behave as a curious mixture of soft and hard links. On my system the file attributes (e.g. read-only/hidden/archive flags) do reflect the state of the target they point towards, however the creation/write/access access fields always seem to equal the creation time of the directory being searched.

I ask because a build tool I was working on decided to cache search results by first translating the file names to absolute ones and filing away the meta-data, leading broken builds when the creation-times of later directories mismatched.

May I rely on the ftCreationTime of "." being equal to the creation time of the folder itself? This would be useful in avoiding unnecessary queries.

For the record here is a quick-and-dirty repro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

static void print(const WIN32_FIND_DATAA *data) {
    printf("name=%s attrib=%08lX creation=%08lX%08lX\n", data->cFileName, data->dwFileAttributes,
        data->ftCreationTime.dwHighDateTime, data->ftCreationTime.dwLowDateTime);
}

int main(void) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data = { 0 };
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFileA("C:\\Windows\\System\\*", &data); 
    print(&data);
    FindNextFileA(handle, &data);
    print(&data);
    FindFirstFileA("C:\\Windows", &data); 
    print(&data);
    FindFirstFileA("C:\\Windows\\System", &data); 
    print(&data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think perhaps the information that you need is that the results of `FindFirstFile` and associated functions are not always guaranteed to be up to date, because for performance reasons they may be retrieved from the cached information in the directory's link to the file rather than by querying the file itself.  If you must have accurate and up-to-date information, use `GetFileInformationByHandle` instead.

Comment: Harry: That's a real pity, actually opening and querying the date of each file in a large project adds several seconds to a large incremental build. I don't think that's the problem here though as the date of the Windows folder hasn't propagated to the ".." link in Windows\System after 5 years+ on one of my systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory...
>
> Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a path to represent the parent of the current directory

It means `.` *is* current directory and you may rely that they attributes are the same. But anyway I don't understand why can't you just ignore the *dot* and *dotdot* files.

Comment: That is what I originally though as well, unfortunately I am not receiving the same information in practice. For instance in the sample above I get a ftCreationTime of 0x01CD6AF0D0D47552 (which is correct according to Explorer) when querying C:\Windows directly, but 0x01CD6B06780841A1 for ".." when iterating through C:\Windows\System\*. I can certainly drop the "." and ".." records, it just means a having to perform a few extra FindFirstFile queries. To be honest I mostly just wanted to know what was going on.

Comment: @doynax, I've just checked it. They are the same on 2 systems. Are you sure you're doing the stuff correctly? What is that file system?

Comment: Curious, I am using NTFS on Windows 8 and behavior is identical the another (Windows 8) system. It very much possible that I am making some mistake. For the record the sample above prints "name=.. attrib=00000010 creation=01CD6B06780841A1" and 
"name=Windows attrib=00000010 creation=01CD6AF0D0D47552", and all calls succeed.

Comment: @donyx, You may rely on attributes of `.`, but you need an extra call to FileFirstFile (or  GetFileAttributesEx) to get creation time of parent if we're talking about `..` file.

Comment: I just tested a Windows 7 and XP system, and they appear to behave similarly. For the record here his the source and executable: https://sites.google.com/site/doynax/FindFirstFileRepro.zip

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I don't suppose you happen to know where this is documented as I'd be more comfortable in relying on it if it was stated somewhere on MSDN? Thinking about it I suppose actually fetching the correct information would likely have required additional I/O for very limited benefit.

Comment: @doynax, I tried to find strict docs, but with no luck. Sorry.

Comment: @doynax: you really should be ignoring the `.` and `..` items when iterating through the file system.

Comment: @Remy: Why is that? Do you know of any circumstances in which the "." data may be incorrect as well? For the record I am not doing a deep search of a directory tree but rather checking the timestamps of a set of files (and batching things up by directory for speed.)

Comment: @doynax: When iterating through the file system, you don't need to, nor should you, process the `.` and `..` for any reason, especially if you are searching for files and iterating subfolders. Your iteration is already in the current folder, and if you need to query the parent folder for anything, you should create an absolute path to the parent based on the current folder's absolute path.

Comment: @doynax: In any case, `.` and `..` have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag applied to them, which you should be filtering out (if you are not already) when searching for files (which do not have that attribute). When iterating subfolders, you must ignore `.` and `..` or else your iteration will get stuck in endless loops.  So processing `.` and `..` really does not offer very much useful information to begin with.

Comment: @Remy: Sorry, I think I'm being unclear. I am not following directories and walking the filesystem rather a "makefile" specifies files as sources/targets and I must check the timestamps of these to see if a recompile is necessary, plus targets implicitly depend on the directory they are in. As an added precaution the file/directory attributes are compared to saved ones from the last run, forcing a rebuild if anything looks fishy.